# Shopify link directly to other item

Tags: shopify, liquid

I have some items in my shopify store that have similar themed items that compliment it well.

I know I could just add an `<a href` link in there, but I'd like to do something that is actually part of liquid, and would also be easier for my non-programmer partner (who also has the authority to make me sleep on the couch :-( ...) to add these links. Is there a way to add a link using the liquid formatting? Something like `This would go great with ${items.ellington-coffee-table-set}!`?

Answer (score 1):

It would be great to be able to access a product like this `collections.my-collection-handle.products.my-product-handle`, but unfortunately [it is not possible to get a product by its handle in liquid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13276655/1367622).

You would have to loop through the collection to find the product like this:

```
{% for product in collections.my-collection-handle.products %}
    {% if product.handle == 'my-product-handle' %}
        {{ 'my product' | link_to: product.url }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

But that looks pretty messy if all you want is a link to the product, and you still have to hard-code the product's handle. This would be simpler:

```
{{ 'my product' | link_to: '/products/my-product-handle' }}
```

Still not ideal, but probably a better alternative than coding an `<a href=...` link manually.